# Looking for Wordpress PDF Converter with Custom Templates?

Tags: plugins, pdf

I work with a number of companies who want bios converted to PDF files for download. The problem is that we cannot find a plugin solution that fits our needs. WP-MPDF has worked in the past, but it is deprecated and does not work with WP Engine (a known issue) where some of our customers host. Essentially, we need a way to create a PDF from a WP template that allows us to exclude certain Advanced Custom Fields and control the overall look of the document. I have considered a workaround by creating a separate Print version with a PDF download on it, but that feels pretty clunky. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new endpoint using [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/), for example `/datasheet/` so your URL would be `example.com/product/datasheet`.

You can then hook in to [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) and check that you are on a product page with this datasheet query var set.

From here, you can then load a separate template which will display the fields you require (and exclude those ACF fields you mention you don't want to display). You can then use PHP's [output buffer functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to copy your template into a string, and pass that to a PFP tool such as [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

```
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['datasheet']) && is_singular('product')) {
   global $post;

   ob_start();
   include(locate_template('template-parts/product/datasheet.php'));
   $datasheet = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();

   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
   $dompdf->loadHtml($datasheet);
   $dompdf->stream($post->post_name . '.pdf');

   exit();
}
```

This is a simplified version of code we use to provide a product datasheet, but should give you something to think about.